# Shared preference with session timeout using countdowntimer

Tags: android, session, android-preferences, countdowntimer, android-sharedpreferences

I want to using startcountdown timer method to change preference value but its not worked.

```
private void startCountdownTimer(final String judul){
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("click"+judul, "1");

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("click"+judul, "0");
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

can i use method ontick and onfinish to change preference like that ?? I want to make session timeout in android actually. so Im using countdown timer to manipulate it.

Comment: You are not commiting the changes to the editor. You have to use editor.commit()

Comment: aw silly me -_- thanks now it works

Answer (score 2):

Use like this is more easy

```
    SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    pref.edit().putString("click"+judul, "1").commit();
```